# Categorize and take note on favorite questions

Tags: feature-request, support

Hi,

Sometimes I see a very interesting question, and want to follow it. But as my favorite list grow bigger, it's hard to find/reference a question again. And I think a favorite question categorizer maybe good for orgnizing my knowledge, such as: here is the folder for basic Java, there is the folder for Grails. And I may take some note for every favorite questions (why I like it, which lessons I should remember?)

In short, is there any way for me to categorize/take note for my favorite questions? (such as tag, or user-created collection). If not, I think it will be a good feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `favorites` function provides a good, basic "remember and watch" facility.

What you are asking for is a full bookmarking and/or note taking system. Why don't you just use a tool *specifically* designed for the job. Download **any good bookmark manager** (or use the one in your browser) to create categories of your favorite content. Or go all out and use a **note-taking and archiving application** like [Evernote](http://evernote.com) or [Onenote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/) and annotate with any notes your desire!

I'd hate to see the Stack Exchange team spending resources on tools which are readily available elsewhere.

Comment: Well, after some research I must admit that Evernote is a good tool, but just think it's still handy if we have some kind of organization over the favorites. Evernote/Zoteros application is useful in taking note & storage & search, but it doesn't give me the overall view about what I liked. I think the site can do this better than outside-applications(statistics & web interface). It's ok if my request seems to be irrelevant now, but I hope it will be reconsidered in future development.

Answer (score 3):

You can get results that are similar to what you are looking for, though you'd need to use [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Use the search term `infavorites:mine [java]`, and you'll see all your favorite [java](/questions/tagged/java) questions.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this trick. Though I really want a more clear way to see the results. Please also notice that my request includes taking note about the favorite questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just adding a tag list to the favorites tab in profile like you see on the right side of the newest unanswered page, or even just a search filter box for non-ninjas would make them a little easier to deal with without trying to recreate Evernote like Robert is concerned about?